# Why am I gettnig runtime error: load of null pointer of type '_Bit_type' (stl_bvector.h)?

Tags: c++

Can anyone tell me why I get this error for this code? The error is on the flower bracket on line 81.

```
Error: runtime error: load of null pointer of type '_Bit_type' (stl_bvector.h)
```

I don't know why I get this error. The question is a word search. I am familiar with Python, and am a beginner in C++.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class Solution {
public:
    int h=0;
    vector<vector<bool>> visited;
    void see(int i,int j,int m,int n,string word,vector<vector<char>> &board,int l){
        if(l==word.size()){

                h=1;
                //cout<<s<<endl;


            return;
        }
        if(i-1>=0 and i-1<m and j>=0 and j<n){


            if(visited[i-1][j]==false){
            visited[i-1][j]=true;    

            this->see(i-1,j,m,n,word,board,l+1);
            visited[i-1][j]=false ;       
            }


        }
        if(i>=0 and i<m and j+1>=0 and j+1<n){

            if(visited[i][j+1]==false){
                visited[i][j+1]=true;

            this->see(i,j+1,m,n,word,board,l+1);
            visited[i][j+1]=false  ;      
            }

        }
        if(i+1>=0 and i+1<m and j>=0 and j<n){

            if(visited[i+1][j]==false){
                visited[i+1][j]=true;

            this->see(i+1,j,m,n,word,board,l+1);
            visited[i+1][j]=false      ;  
            }
        }
        if(i>=0 and i<m and j-1>=0 and j-1<n){

         if(visited[i][j-1]==false){
             visited[i][j-1]=true;

            this->see(i,j-1,m,n,word,board,l+1);
            visited[i][j-1]=false     ;   
            }

        }


    }

    bool exist(vector<vector<char>>& board, string word) {
        visited.resize(board.size());
        for(int i=0;i<board.size();i++){
            for(int j=0;j<board[0].size();j++){
                visited[i][j]=false;
            }
        }

        int m=board.size(),n=board[0].size();
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                if(board[i][j]==word[0]){
                    visited[i][j]=true;

                    this->see(i,j,m,n,word,board,1);
                    if(h==1){
                        return(true);
                    }
                    visited[i][j]=false;
                }
                }
        }
        return(false);

    }
};
```

Comment: Unrelated: the first two lines of your program put it in an extremely vulnerable position. The first line includes the entire c++ standard library. That's a lot of stuff and you're using almost none of it. This dramatically slows the build time and leave you with a huge number of identifiers you need to avoid. Fortunately they are all in the `std` namespace where they are safe. Except the second line pulls everything in the `std` namespace into conflict with whatever you define in the global namespace. This is very risky.

Comment: The one-letter variable naming makes this code harder to read than necessary. A 1 letter variable contains little-to no contextual information about what the variable represents and how it should be used and also makes it easy to accidentally substitute one variable for another while at the same time making it difficult to spot the accidental substitution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `exist` function.  You start with a `visited.resize()`, which will resize `visited` to have `board.size()` empty vectors.  When you attempt to write to `visited[i][j]` in the following loop, you'll get this error.

The simplest fix is to also create all the subvectors when you resize `visited`:

```
visited.resize(board.size(), vector<bool>(board[0].size());
```

That does have one issue with it, though:  if `board` is empty, you'll access out of bounds for the default value for all the subvectors.

Once you have that, the following loops are not needed, since the vectors will have all elements set to `false`.

You can also move the declarations for `m` and `n` up to the start of `exist`, and use them when resizing `visited`.